# Can I use 3rd generation Intel processor with Gigabyte GA-h61M-S2V-B3 rev 1.1?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

Will this processor and this motherboard work together?

> [dual core 2.6 Ghz / 2M cache **G1610**](http://ark.intel.com/products/71072/Intel-Celeron-Processor-G1610-2M-Cache-2_60-GHz)

Motherboard:

> [Gigabyte GA-h61M-S2V-B3 ***rev 1.1***](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3875#bios)

I tried but I failed, then when I went to the Gigabyte website I found that the BIOS can be updated, then the processor will work, so how can that happen? How can I make something newer work with old technology, especially when we talk a bout different generation?

The problem is that I don't know how to make the processor work with motherboard, and I thought that they will work with each other because the Gigabyte website give me an information a bout a new bios [with new version F8] can make the processor work. I don't have another processor to make the update, the only way to update the BIOS is to give the motherboard to any maintenance engineer to make the update and try it and that means more money, so how I can be sure that updated BIOS will make the processor work before I spend the money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True, you can update BIOS for gain access to certain CPU, but that CPU is not listed on the supported CPU's for that motherboard. So, is unknown or surely you will not use that CPU on that motherboard. Look it for yourself:

http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=3875

Even if you update, you only gain support for the upper cpu's from the list (F8 update).

Anyway you MUST use older cpu from another computer (one friend or something else) for update BIOS and bring it back.

EDIT: I will give you some hope. The H61M northbridge wich uses that motherboard is **CAPABLE** of use that CPU : http://www.asrock.com/mb/cpu.asp?Model=H61M . But like is not not list in the Gigabyte list I can't give you a 100% of success. Like is capable, try to upgrade bios anyway, searching for an older 1155 non 22nm, conect it, copy the bios to a usb, and use the bios utility from BIOS for update sucess and put your G1610 again.

Comment: look here http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3875#bios                                                              for description Improve [ET6 compatibility when use Intel 22nm processors]

Comment: you will see that it can be updated for 22 nm 3rd generation processor

Comment: @adam True, in the list, the F8 update specify 22nm CPU, but any of them is the "G1610". Well I will improve this answer, giving you some expectations.

Comment: I found that the processor not fit motherboard

Answer (score 0):

The Processor G1610 will not work with this motherboard

I went to Gigabyte website again and I search for [CPU Support List](http://www.gigabyte.us/support-downloads/cpu-support.aspx) ,and I put the specification ,and I found that this Processor don't work with that motherboard.

This motherboard specially Doesn't accept new version of BIOS for that Processor .

[Her is a comparison link](http://www.gigabyte.us/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?v=AE72F6F9D4ADD0D7ABAFF6E317C9D2B4F94CFD198AFEB846BDC33D80B0C165BE&s=Socket%201155&cs=Intel%20H61)